# Preventing blank records being written to database is SQL3 & Python

Tags: python, sqlite

This is the first time I am posting so hope I do this correctly.

Can anyone assist me with a problem that I do not seem to be able to get past. I have had a good google but not found an answer. I am using Python 3.7 and SQL3

I am trying to prevent a record being written to the database if the 'f_name' field is blank.

I have tried to put a condition on the conn.commit() from not writing - did not work
I have tried to do a condition and indent the c.execute if f-name is blank but that has not worked as I guess it has not got the input yet.

if I print out f_name after the c.execute I get ".!entry2" regardless if there is an input or not if that makes any difference or gives a clue. I am guessing it is being written directly to the database and does not exist as a variable.

The error check I use is as follows (I have used it successfully elsewhere so it should be ok)

```
if f_name =="":
          print("No valid Data in First name field")
          return
else:
          conn.commit()
```

and I tried using the error check on the conn.commit() but I am guessing it is auto commiting.

Can anyone please give me an idea of how to prevent a blank f_name being accepted in this scenario?

Here is the code being called -

```
def submit():
    # Connect to database
    conn = sqlite3.connect('address_book.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    six_month_reminder = ("f")
    annual_reminder = ("f")
    six_month_reminder_sent = ("f")
    annual_reminder_sent = ("f")

    # Insert Into Table
    c.execute("INSERT INTO addresses VALUES (:f_name, :l_name, :address, :city, :state, :zipcode, :six_month_reminder, :annual_reminder, :six_month_reminder_sent, :annual_reminder_sent)",
            {
                'f_name': f_name.get(),
                'l_name': l_name.get(),
                'address': address.get(),
                'city': city.get(),
                'state': state.get(),
                'zipcode': zipcode.get(),
                'six_month_reminder': six_month_reminder,
                'annual_reminder': annual_reminder,
                'six_month_reminder_sent': six_month_reminder_sent,
                'annual_reminder_sent':annual_reminder_sent
            })

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for contributing ot SO.

In your code chunk it is missing the part in which you declare `f_name`, `l_name`, `address`...

Assuming you have declared those in a chunk you didn't write in the question, I assume here that `fname` is set and it is a dictionary; the most straigthforward way is to check when performing the `get()`:

```py
    ...
    annual_reminder_sent = ("f")

    if f_name.get() == '' or f_name.get() is None:
        return
    ...
```

EDIT: the second statement for the `or` is needed as in case of key is not in the dictionary `get` will return `None`, see [Python documentation about](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get).

In the case you missed that, the use of `get()` is supposed for dictionaries. For example if you try this in Python REPL:

```
>> d = {
   "key1": 1,
   "key2": 2
}
>> print(d.get("key1"))
```

will return `1`. Dictionaries are key-value maps.

In your case it seems you are doing something wrong as you are using `get()` on names that are not dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to post as little as possible so as not to get into trouble for being too verbose. This is part of a larger program where f_name is declared as a button i.e. to Create Text Boxes
f_name = Entry(root, width = 30)
f_name.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx=20, pady=(20,0))

Comment: Well done, that actually does sort out the problem. I have put your f_name.get() =="" before the conn.commit and it does not write the row if the input is blank. Thank you. Good job.